# Editor - HTML Markup Intellisense

Tags: html, telerik, intellisense

In my company we've implemented the visual studio editor in a web browser.
I want to add html markup (and telerik controllers) intellisense.
I've found this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372314.aspx

Is this the right direction, or do you have something else that can help.

Comment: Unless you work for Microsoft this question doesn't make much sense. Visual Studio is the name of a particular product. I believe you meant to say that you've implemented a web based IDE. It may be a Visual Studio 'clone' but that does not make it Visual Studio.

Comment: Hi. It's not visual studio clone. We've created a web based edito like visual studio has. Its an extension.

Comment: So you created a clone of VS that is web-based. You know MS now has this in hosted VS? And it has intellisense. Why reinvent the wheel? Or do you mean you created an extension for the MS web based VS?

Comment: I work at a BPM company, and our platform is built with .net framework. They've created an editor that look like the one in visual studio. We have the ability to write markup inside it. I want to create a schema that will give me intellisense for the html, asp.net controls and the custom controls that we have (telerik)